# Why does laravel installer not work when valet is running

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

When running Valet+ in macos Catalina running the `laravel new blog` command in terminal results in the error "cURL error 52: Empty reply from server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)".

However if I stop valet with `valet stop` it works fine.

Is there a way to avoid having to stop Valet+?

Answer (score 0):

it could be caused by a variety of problems.
first see your nginx log and see what is happening but what I think is its the openssl problem that is trying to catch a website that is ssl and it's not using ssl.
try to run :

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew cleanup
```

and see what happens.

Comment: I can no longer replicate my previous issue where ```laravel new blog```would work when valet was stopped.  It will now not work at all.